# Clojure Liberator: get request body twice

Tags: clojure, liberator

Let's assume, that I've got an endpoint `POST /endpoint` that takes JSON as input data:

```
POST /endpoint
{
  "resource": {
    "name": "great"
  }
}
```

Now, I want to check whether the incoming JSON is valid. I thought that `:malformed?` hook would be a great place for doing that.

So I came up with such a code:

```
(ANY "/endpoint" [] 
     (resource
      :allowed-methods [:post]
      :available-media-types ["application/json"]
      :malformed? (fn [ctx] (let [body (get-body-from-request ctx)
                                   is-malformed (not (is-body-valid body))]
                                is-malformed)
      :post! (fn [ctx] (let [body (get-body-from-request ctx)]
                          (create-an-object body)))
      :handle-created (fn [ctx] {:method :post :body (:body @request)})))
```

So my intention was:

- get the `body` from request, check if it's valid (`is-body-valid`)
- in `post!` hook, use the `body` again and do real work (`create-an-object`)

The problem here is the `get-body-from-request` function:

```
(defn get-body-from-request [ctx]
  (json/read-str (slurp (get-in ctx [:request :body])) :key-fn keyword))
```

It works perfectly but the `body` is an `InputStream`,  so I can read it only once.

Is there a way to use `body` of the request in more than one hook NOT using atoms?

The solutions coming to my mind:

1. A middleware wrapper that adds a string version of `body` to the `ctx` param.
2. Pass the result of `malformed?` to `post!`...
3. Use atoms.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, it was pretty easy, there's of course a wrapper that does that...

`[ring-json-params "0.1.3"]`

Then you just wrap your app handler:

```
(ns my.app
  (:require [ring.middleware.json :refer [wrap-json-params]]))

(def app
  (-> handler
      (wrap-json-params)))
```

and in your `ctx` object you've got a `json-params` object:

```
:malformed? (fn [ctx] (let [params (get-in ctx [:request :json-params])]
                        false))
```